# DTFT of one-sided signal

Tags: fft

When taking the DTFT of a discrete-time signal x[n]=a×u[n], the book "Signals and Systems" by Chi-Tsong Chen claims that the result is 1/(1−a⋅exp(−j⋅w⋅T)); however, many other sources claim the DTFT is 1/(1−a⋅exp(−j⋅w)) without the T term.

The book I have states that x[n]=x(nT) by definition and the DTFT by definition is Xd(w)= the summation from n=−inf to n=+inf of x(n⋅T)exp(−jwnT).

Can someone explain the reason for the differences?

Comment: Hi, this is a site primarily to ask questions about programming - yes there is a FFT tag - but I wonder whether you would get better results for this question on the math site......  Good choice of name though!

Comment: The site is http://math.stackexchange.com/ and there are questions tagged fourier-analysis

Answer (score 0):

The two formulas do not contradict each other, it is just normalized frequency vs. regular frequency.

You probably missed the difference between the capital Omega and non-capital omega.

- omega is the regular angular frequency and has unit (Hz).
- Omega is the normalized frequency (Omega = omega T). It is -pi for minus half of sampling rate and +pi for half sampling rate.

So you have exp(-i Omega) = exp(-i omega T).